# (discord.py) change discord avatar with someone's avatar url

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to change my bot's avatar with the avatar url of someone in my server. The code isn't working. Any help?

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        avatar_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/834942728953135115/315376d20a50a86450e9e3b91ff66123.webp?size=1024" #avatar url of someone in my server
        await bot.user.edit(avatar=avatar_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer says you have to have a bytes-like object, which is true. Adding onto it though: you can retrieve the image as a bytes-like object with requests like: `img = requests.get(url).content` which you can then use in the `await bot.user.edit(avatar=img)` (replace url with your url or make a variable called url that contains the url) (and ofc import requests at the start of your script)

as someone has pointed out `requests` is sequential and thus blocking the async loop, which you dont really want (though for just updating it once it wont hurt too much :D). So if you want to do it properly, you should look at [the docs for `aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html)

Comment: Since discord uses async functions, you might want to use an async http library rather than `requests`, e.g. `aiohttp` or `httpx`

Comment: Thats a very good point, I dont know too much about those libs though. Feel free to edit my comment.

Comment: @Oli is correct it is called `blocking` you can read more and see an example [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=blocking#what-does-blocking-mean) in the d.py docs

Answer (score 0):

according to the *[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20edit#discord.ClientUser.edit)* the avatar gets a byte-object or in other words, you have to use open("file",'rb') in order to change the avatar.
you can also change the avatar manually *[here](https://discord.com/developers/applications)* by going to the application your bot is on and then going to bot and changing the avatar by uploading an image.